How to upload multiple files to a private folder in webform
I created a webform with a File upload field. For the file settings, I set 'Private files' as the 'File upload destination' and allowed a maximum of 3 files to be uploaded, with the option to remove them. This setup works with my admin account, but it does not allow file uploads when I access the form as an anonymous user (e.g., in incognito mode). I want to enable anonymous users to upload files to the private folder. How can I resolve this?
Thank you

What does "does not allow" mean, technically?

When I submit the form, it shows 'File upload in progress. Uploaded file may be lost. Click OK to submit the form without finishing the file upload or cancel to return to form.' It looks like this progress will never be done, so I can't upload any files as an anonymous user.

That information belongs in the Question, which is how this site works.
